# How to filter rows with multiple conditions

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, rows, multiple-conditions

I am new to R. I'm trying to filter rows from a data.frame (df) based on multiple conditions:

An example of my data.frame:
[image of my df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If7Gx.png)

*df:*

```
SNPA    SNPB    value       block1              block2                                  score_T
A1      A22     0.379927    A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6   A22|A23|A24|A25                         12 
A2      A23     0.449074    A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6   A22|A23|A24|A25                         25 
A3      A24     0.464135    A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6   A22|A23|A24|A25                         584 
A4      A22     0.328866    A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6   A22|A23|A24|A25                         51 
A5      A22     0.326026    A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6   A22|A23|A24|A25                         64 
A22     A27     0.57169     A22|A23|A24|A25     A27|A28|A29|A30|A31                     77 
A23     A28     0.416178    A22|A23|A24|A25     A27|A28|A29|A30|A31                     90 
A24     A29     0.456144    A22|A23|A24|A25     A27|A28|A29|A30|A31                     103
A34     A39     0.379927    A31|A32|A33|A34     A39|A40|A41|A42                         116
A34     A40     0.759074    A31|A32|A33|A34     A39|A40|A41|A42                         129
A34     A41     0.562303    A31|A32|A33|A34     A39|A40|A41|A42                         142
A39     A57     0.322303    A39|A40|A41|A42     A52|A53|A54|A55|A56|A57|A58|A59|A60|A61 25
A40     A57     0.372303    A39|A40|A41|A42     A52|A53|A54|A55|A56|A57|A58|A59|A60|A61 198
A41     A57     0.562303    A39|A40|A41|A42     A52|A53|A54|A55|A56|A57|A58|A59|A60|A61 356
```

What I want is to use `dplyr` to keep only the rows where the blocks (block1 and block2) have at least two SNPs (from the column SNPA for block1, and SNPB for block2) each, and remove pairs of blocks containing 1 SNP (example: rows 9 to 14).

Result wanted: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGhAl.png)

```
SNPA    SNPB    value       block1              block2                                  score_T
A1      A22     0.379927    A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6   A22|A23|A24|A25                         12 
A2      A23     0.449074    A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6   A22|A23|A24|A25                         25 
A3      A24     0.464135    A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6   A22|A23|A24|A25                         584 
A4      A22     0.328866    A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6   A22|A23|A24|A25                         51 
A5      A22     0.326026    A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6   A22|A23|A24|A25                         64 
A22     A27     0.57169     A22|A23|A24|A25     A27|A28|A29|A30|A31                     77 
A23     A28     0.416178    A22|A23|A24|A25     A27|A28|A29|A30|A31                     90 
A24     A29     0.456144    A22|A23|A24|A25     A27|A28|A29|A30|A31                     103
```

Do you have any idea how I can do that?

```
result <- df %>% group_by(block1, block2) %>% filter(...) %>% summarise(mean_s = mean(score_T), number = n())
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by atleast two SNPs? Two ("pairwise")unique SNPs?

Comment: I will try to explain with an example: taking the row 10 in my *df*: `A34     A40     0.759074    A31|A32|A33|A34     A39|A40|A41|A42                         129` . the *block1* contain 4 SNPS (`A31|A32|A33|A34`) but only one of them (*A34*) is present in the column (*SNPA*), so this row thould be removed (idem for rows 9, 11, 12, 13 and 14). Row 14: *block2* contain only 1 SNP (*A57*) from the column `SNPB`, so should be removed also, ... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat slow `base-dplyr` solution. Some issues with this solution include the need to manually set "blocks" and "snps" in our filter function. One could probably automate this process.

```
my_filter <- function(df,block, snp){
   res<-strsplit(df[[block]],"|", fixed= TRUE)
   lengths(lapply(res, function(x) which(x %in% df[[snp]]))) > 1

 }
 df %>% 
 filter(my_filter(., "block1", "SNPA"), my_filter(., "block2","SNPB"))
  SNPA SNPB    value            block1              block2 score_T
1   A1  A22 0.379927 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      12
2   A2  A23 0.449074 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      25
3   A3  A24 0.464135 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25     584
4   A4  A22 0.328866 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      51
5   A5  A22 0.326026 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      64
6  A22  A27 0.571690   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31      77
7  A23  A28 0.416178   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31      90
8  A24  A29 0.456144   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31     103
```

Data:

```
df <-structure(list(SNPA = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A22", 
"A23", "A24", "A34", "A34", "A34", "A39", "A40", "A41"), SNPB = c("A22", 
"A23", "A24", "A22", "A22", "A27", "A28", "A29", "A39", "A40", 
"A41", "A57", "A57", "A57"), value = c(0.379927, 0.449074, 0.464135, 
0.328866, 0.326026, 0.57169, 0.416178, 0.456144, 0.379927, 0.759074, 
0.562303, 0.322303, 0.372303, 0.562303), block1 = c("A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6", 
"A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6", "A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6", "A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6", 
"A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6", "A22|A23|A24|A25", "A22|A23|A24|A25", "A22|A23|A24|A25", 
"A31|A32|A33|A34", "A31|A32|A33|A34", "A31|A32|A33|A34", "A39|A40|A41|A42", 
"A39|A40|A41|A42", "A39|A40|A41|A42"), block2 = c("A22|A23|A24|A25", 
"A22|A23|A24|A25", "A22|A23|A24|A25", "A22|A23|A24|A25", "A22|A23|A24|A25", 
"A27|A28|A29|A30|A31", "A27|A28|A29|A30|A31", "A27|A28|A29|A30|A31", 
"A39|A40|A41|A42", "A39|A40|A41|A42", "A39|A40|A41|A42", "A52|A53|A54|A55|A56|A57|A58|A59|A60|A61", 
"A52|A53|A54|A55|A56|A57|A58|A59|A60|A61", "A52|A53|A54|A55|A56|A57|A58|A59|A60|A61"
), score_T = c(12L, 25L, 584L, 51L, 64L, 77L, 90L, 103L, 116L, 
129L, 142L, 25L, 198L, 356L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: It works on a small dataset, thank you very much. 
I hope it will go faster for large data sets in a list.

Comment: Glad to help. It is an interesting question, I will be looking at a possible way to write up a purely `dplyr` solution. You can use `setDT` on a larger dataset and might presumably get some speed improvement(if it is slow).

Comment: Is there any other way to speed the script? It takes many hours on big data frames.

Comment: You can try to use `stringr` for the string manipulations and use the new `dplyr` `across` to avoid the slow parts of this solution ie `strsplit` and using `lapply`. `across` would replace `lapply`. Did you try using `setDT` and `data.table`?

Answer (score 0):

`toString(unique(SNPA))` will return a character vector of length one, which will be matched with `block1` using `setdiff`, then we apply this process to each row using `purrr::map2`

```
#Here a toy example to understand setdiff, strsplit, and length
> length(strsplit(setdiff(toString(unique(df[1:5,'SNPA'])), df[1,'block1']),',')[[1]])
[1] 5

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
     group_by(block1,block2) %>% 
     mutate(A = purrr::map2_dbl(toString(unique(SNPA)), block1, ~length(strsplit(setdiff(.x, .y),',')[[1]])), 
            B = purrr::map2_dbl(toString(unique(SNPB)), block2, ~length(strsplit(setdiff(.x, .y),',')[[1]]))) %>% 
     filter(A>2 & B>2)

# A tibble: 8 x 8
# Groups:   block1, block2 [2]
  SNPA  SNPB  value block1            block2              score_T     A     B
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>             <chr>                 <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A1    A22   0.380 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6 A22|A23|A24|A25          12     5     3
2 A2    A23   0.449 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6 A22|A23|A24|A25          25     5     3
3 A3    A24   0.464 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6 A22|A23|A24|A25         584     5     3
4 A4    A22   0.329 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6 A22|A23|A24|A25          51     5     3
5 A5    A22   0.326 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6 A22|A23|A24|A25          64     5     3
6 A22   A27   0.572 A22|A23|A24|A25   A27|A28|A29|A30|A31      77     3     3
7 A23   A28   0.416 A22|A23|A24|A25   A27|A28|A29|A30|A31      90     3     3
8 A24   A29   0.456 A22|A23|A24|A25   A27|A28|A29|A30|A31     103     3     3
```