# Fast way to compare concatenated string with values in vector

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, data.table

I have a data frame with two columns with SNP ids, 'block1' and 'block2'. In these columns, the individual ids are concatenated and separated by `|`, e.g. in row 1 in 'block1': `"A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6"`.

For each row in 'block1', I want to check if each individual id is present in the 'SNPA' column. In the same way I want to check if each id in 'block2' is in 'SNPB' column.

If the blocks (block1 and block2) have at least two SNPs each in a row (from the column SNPA for block1, and SNPB for block2), the row should be kept. Other rows with less than two matching SNPs should be removed, e.g. rows 9 to 14.

Example:

> Taking the **row 10** in my df:
> block1 contain **4 SNPS** (`A31|A32|A33|A34`) but only one of them (`A34`) is
> present in the column (`SNPA`), so this row should be removed (**idem for
> rows 9, 11, 12, 13 and 14**). **Row 14**: block2 contain only **1 SNP** (`A57`)
> from the `SNPB` column , so should be removed also, ... etc.

I tried the @NelsonGon [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559555/how-to-filter-rows-with-multiple-conditions), but it takes a lot of time (several days on a cluster):

```
my_filter <- function(df,block, snp){
   res<-strsplit(df[[block]],"|", fixed= TRUE)
   lengths(lapply(res, function(x) which(x %in% df[[snp]]))) > 1

 }
 df %>% 
 filter(my_filter(., "block1", "SNPA"), my_filter(., "block2","SNPB"))
  SNPA SNPB    value            block1              block2 score_T
1   A1  A22 0.379927 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      12
2   A2  A23 0.449074 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      25
3   A3  A24 0.464135 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25     584
4   A4  A22 0.328866 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      51
5   A5  A22 0.326026 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      64
6  A22  A27 0.571690   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31      77
7  A23  A28 0.416178   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31      90
8  A24  A29 0.456144   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31     103
```

**Is there another way much more faster for big dataframes (2 million rows) ?**

Thanks for help

My data example:

```
df <-structure(list(SNPA = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A22", 
"A23", "A24", "A34", "A34", "A34", "A39", "A40", "A41"), SNPB = c("A22", 
"A23", "A24", "A22", "A22", "A27", "A28", "A29", "A39", "A40", 
"A41", "A57", "A57", "A57"), value = c(0.379927, 0.449074, 0.464135, 
0.328866, 0.326026, 0.57169, 0.416178, 0.456144, 0.379927, 0.759074, 
0.562303, 0.322303, 0.372303, 0.562303), block1 = c("A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6", 
"A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6", "A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6", "A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6", 
"A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6", "A22|A23|A24|A25", "A22|A23|A24|A25", "A22|A23|A24|A25", 
"A31|A32|A33|A34", "A31|A32|A33|A34", "A31|A32|A33|A34", "A39|A40|A41|A42", 
"A39|A40|A41|A42", "A39|A40|A41|A42"), block2 = c("A22|A23|A24|A25", 
"A22|A23|A24|A25", "A22|A23|A24|A25", "A22|A23|A24|A25", "A22|A23|A24|A25", 
"A27|A28|A29|A30|A31", "A27|A28|A29|A30|A31", "A27|A28|A29|A30|A31", 
"A39|A40|A41|A42", "A39|A40|A41|A42", "A39|A40|A41|A42", "A52|A53|A54|A55|A56|A57|A58|A59|A60|A61", 
"A52|A53|A54|A55|A56|A57|A58|A59|A60|A61", "A52|A53|A54|A55|A56|A57|A58|A59|A60|A61"
), score_T = c(12L, 25L, 584L, 51L, 64L, 77L, 90L, 103L, 116L, 
129L, 142L, 25L, 198L, 356L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it is using regex & `str_count` a vectorized function from `stringr` pacakge

```
my_filter <- function(dat) {
  SNPA_list <- unique(dat[["SNPA"]])
  SNPB_list <- unique(dat[["SNPB"]])
  # Based on the list create pattern for matching the block
  # to ensure it match the whole word it need to end with either | or $ (end of line)
  pattern_SNPA <- paste0("(", paste(SNPA_list, collapse = "(\\||$)|"), ")")
  pattern_SNPB <- paste0("(", paste(SNPB_list, collapse = "(\\||$)|"), ")")
  
  
  dat[["check_block_1"]] <- str_count(string = dat[["block1"]], pattern = pattern_SNPA)
  dat[["check_block_2"]] <- str_count(string = dat[["block2"]], pattern = pattern_SNPB)
  
  dat %>% filter(check_block_1 > 1 & check_block_2 > 1)
}
```

Timing similar to what @akrun did

```
> df1 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 1e3), ]
> dim(df1)
[1] 14000     6
> system.time({f1(df1)})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.040   0.005   0.046
```

Here is the output using your original data

```
  SNPA SNPB    value            block1              block2 score_T
1   A1  A22 0.379927 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      12
2   A2  A23 0.449074 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      25
3   A3  A24 0.464135 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25     584
4   A4  A22 0.328866 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      51
5   A5  A22 0.326026 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      64
6  A22  A27 0.571690   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31      77
7  A23  A28 0.416178   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31      90
8  A24  A29 0.456144   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31     103
```

Comment: Thank you !! Its work perfectly and I reduced the running time from many hours to few secends.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping over each element of `list` i.e. each row of the data, an option is to convert the `list` to a `matrix` after appending `NA` at the end (where list elements are of lesser length than the maximum length), use `%in%` with `rowSums` to do this in a vectorized way.

```
f1 <- function(dat) {
   lst1 <- strsplit(dat[["block1"]], "|", fixed = TRUE)
   mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
   m1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx ))
   i1 <- rowSums(`dim<-`(m1 %in% dat[["SNPA"]], dim(m1))) > 1
   
   lst2 <- strsplit(dat[["block2"]], "|", fixed = TRUE)
   my <- max(lengths(lst2))
   m2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst2, `length<-`, my))
   i2 <- rowSums(`dim<-`(m2 %in% dat[["SNPB"]], dim(m2))) > 1
   dat[i1 & i2, ]
   }
   
f1(df)
#   SNPA SNPB    value            block1              block2 score_T
#1   A1  A22 0.379927 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      12
#2   A2  A23 0.449074 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      25
#3   A3  A24 0.464135 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25     584
#4   A4  A22 0.328866 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      51
#5   A5  A22 0.326026 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      64
#6  A22  A27 0.571690   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31      77
#7  A23  A28 0.416178   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31      90
#8  A24  A29 0.456144   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31     103
```

#### Benchmarks

Checked the timings on a slightly bigger data

```
 df1 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 1e3), ]
 dim(df1)
 #[1] 14000    6



system.time({
    df1 %>% 
    filter(my_filter(., "block1", "SNPA"), my_filter(., "block2","SNPB"))
    })
#user  system elapsed 
#  5.195   1.909   7.070

system.time({f1(df1)})
#user  system elapsed 
# 0.051   0.007   0.058
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
subset(df, sapply(strsplit(block1, '|', fixed = TRUE), 
                  function(x) sum(x %in% SNPA)) > 1 & 
           sapply(strsplit(block2, '|', fixed = TRUE), 
                  function(x) sum(x %in% SNPB)) > 1)

#  SNPA SNPB    value            block1              block2 score_T
#1   A1  A22 0.379927 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      12
#2   A2  A23 0.449074 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      25
#3   A3  A24 0.464135 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25     584
#4   A4  A22 0.328866 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      51
#5   A5  A22 0.326026 A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6     A22|A23|A24|A25      64
#6  A22  A27 0.571690   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31      77
#7  A23  A28 0.416178   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31      90
#8  A24  A29 0.456144   A22|A23|A24|A25 A27|A28|A29|A30|A31     103
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit faster using `stringi::stri_split_fixed`. Also possible to crank it up a little bit more with `data.table`'s fast version of `%in%`, `%chin%`, optimised for character vectors.

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table) # for %chin%

h1 = function(d){
  m1 = stri_split_fixed(d$block1, "|", simplify = TRUE)
  m2 = stri_split_fixed(d$block2, "|", simplify = TRUE)
  d[rowSums(`dim<-`(m1 %in% d$SNPA, dim(m1))) > 1 &
      (rowSums(`dim<-`(m2 %in% d$SNPB, dim(m2))) > 1), ]
}

h2 = function(d){
  m1 = stri_split_fixed(d$block1, "|", simplify = TRUE)
  m2 = stri_split_fixed(d$block2, "|", simplify = TRUE)
  d[rowSums(`dim<-`(m1 %chin% d$SNPA, dim(m1))) > 1 &
      (rowSums(`dim<-`(m2 %chin% d$SNPB, dim(m2))) > 1), ]
}

dat <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 1e5), ]
# nrows same order of magnitude as OP data

microbenchmark(
  {sinh_r = sinh(dat)},
  {akrun_r = akrun(dat)},
  {h1_r = h1(dat)},
  {h2_r = h2(dat)},
  times = 5L)

# Unit: seconds
#                    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#   {sinh_r = sinh(dat) } 10.124904 10.143505 10.273366 10.187132 10.188580 10.722707     5
# {akrun_r = akrun(dat) }  6.177953  6.261431  7.181860  7.575715  7.763312  8.130890     5
#       {h1_r = h1(dat) }  1.979913  2.247698  2.655028  2.371420  2.477972  4.198140     5
#       {h2_r = h2(dat) }  1.778722  1.859815  2.191478  2.244570  2.502178  2.572105     5
```

---

```
all.equal(akrun_r, h1_r)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(akrun_r, sinh_r[ , 1:6])
# [1] TRUE
```

Ronak's code didn't give the same output on the toy data (which have duplicates in the SNP cols), hence not included here.

Comment: @Ab_Lh Just curious of your feedback if my solution worked the way you wanted? Cheers